# Will vote_fu work without a voter model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just looking into [vote_fu](https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu) for a public page where people can vote on content.  I am interested in implementing this, but there will be no model to `act_as_voter`, only a model to `act_as_votable`.  Is this doable?  Anyone have experience with this?

Many thanks as always.

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd not recommend doing that. The gem/plugin is built around the idea of a `voter` model. You might be able to tweak your implementation by creating your own migrations and overriding included methods to be still able to use vote_fu, but IMO that would be hardly worth it.

Thinking about an anonymous voting process in its simplest form you should be a lot faster by rolling your own custom version.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info.  I think I might learn more by 'rolling my own' too.  All the best!